# Remove background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background

I am using odd and even bgcolor for a table.

I have a single table structure in which I am doing odd and even bgcolor. I don't want bgcolor(want white) in few `<tr>` in between that table.

If I am putting any class in the `<tr>` or `<td>` the js is overwriting it.

Hi is what I am doing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".myTable tr:odd").addClass("myTable-alt");
});
```

/*css*/

```
.myTable-alt  {
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `!important` is one way, another way would be to change your CSS.

```
.myTable-alt  {
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.myTable-alt.no-color { /* for elements with BOTH classes */
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

And for the `<tr>` that you want to have a white background, they can look like:

```
<tr class="myTable-alt no-color">
```

Because *all* of the `odd` `<tr>`s are going to have the `.myTable-alt` class, and you can add a *second* class to the few that you want to modify.

**NOTE:** if the `background-color` on the *parent* element is the same as `.myTable-alt`, then that's why the `even` rows are not white.  If that's the case, then you can force it like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".myTable tr:odd").addClass("myTable-alt");
    $('.myTable tr:even').css('background-color', '#fff');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a more specific selector like `tr.newClass` or the css `!important` keyword in the new class so that the styles will not be overridden by `.myTable-alt`.

For eg,

```
table tr.newClass{
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

or

```
.newClass{
  background-color: #FFF !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support IE8, you can use `nth-child` to zebra stripe your table.

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
}
```

You can create a class to override that color on the desired rows.  Just make sure that this selector definition is after the above one in your style sheet.

```
tr.special {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0vqo4jrz/)